# angular 4 *ngIf not working as expected

Tags: angular

I am displaying a bunch of `li` links that i get from a web service, all of those links have `title` and `slug` property.

The problem is, i do not want to display a `li` if the `slug` property is `home`, however the `*ngIf` directive is not making a difference in my code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let page of pages">
                <li *ngIf="page.slug!==home">
                    <a routerLink="{{ page.slug }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
                </li>
            </ng-container>
```

I get all the pages including the one with the `slug` of `home`. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `home` into the `''`. Without `''` Angular tries to find a property with name `home`, and because there is no such property with name `home`, it returns `undefined`. So comparing with your `page.slug` it returns true every time.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let page of pages">
     <li *ngIf="page.slug !== 'home'">
          <a routerLink="{{ page.slug }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
     </li>
</ng-container>
```